# Cyclic dependency in module 'Darwin': in XCode 9.2

Tags: ios, xcode, darwin

Getting this weird error suddenly.

[image]

I have tried cleaning and deleting the derived data and also tried changing the Enable modules flag in build settings.

[image]
Does anyone know how to fix this errors in Xcode.

**EDIT**: The errors only show up while archiving, I can successfully build and run in Simulator.

It can be easily reproduced by just installing [Core plot](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot) and [Google speech api](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ios-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Swift/Speech-gRPC-Streaming) together via Cocoapods.

Comment: Are you using "New Build System" or "Standard Build System"? (To check: File->Workspace Settings)

Comment: @DisableR I am using Standard Build System but I checked with New build system as well and it fails without any errors!

Comment: Check this same issue here:  https://github.com/google/j2objc/issues/709

Comment: Thanks @MZubairShamshad But I already looked at it and all my search paths are non-recursive.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, fixed by replacing `#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>` with `#import <CommonCrypto/CommonHMAC.h>` in my Swift bridging header file. The former includes `CommonKeyDerivation.h`, which eventually include `time.h`. However, gRPC has a `time.h` file as well, as it has header priority in header search path, its `timer.h` version is used instead of the system one, which caused to the issue you mentioned. Hope this helps.